# In Visual Studio, change the keyboard to use an F key for "execute sql"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

In Visual Studio 2010, I have a Database Project. I can use this without issue to view, edit, create sprocs, etc.

How can I change the keyboard to allow me to use an F key for "execute sql" as I would use F5 in MSSMS. I can't seem to find the right binding sequence in Tools-Options-Keyboards and figured it would be faster to ask the community, so I can focus on writing code atm.

Much obliged. (And yes, I admit I'm being lazy, but my googlefu has given up the ghost this morning and I'm just curious, it's not stopping me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was having the same issue... I also bound F5 to `QueryDesigner.ExecuteSQL`. No go. Then I bound F5 to `Data.SqlEditorExecuteSQL`. Still no go... But then I *unbound* F5 from `QueryDesigner.ExecuteSQ`L and it worked... now I can hit F5 and execute a query. I was worried there for a bit.

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 14):

**For VS 2013 and VS 2015**

Command I found to work was **SQL.TSqlEditorExecuteQuery**

I use F5 as shortcut but remember use drop-down **'Use new shortcut in' = Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor**

*Some steps:*

1. Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard
2. Go to **SQL.TSqlEditorExecuteQuery**

*Hint: Paste it into the "Show Commands Containing" textbox because it is a long list.*

3. Set **'Use new shortcut in'** to **Microsoft Sql Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor**

*This way F5 will still keep the same behavior when coding C# etc.*

4. Click in **'Press shortcut keys'** and hit the **F5** key
5. Click **Assign** (required)
6. Click **Ok**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Tools>Options > Keyboard > QueryDesigner.ExecuteSQL > Create new short Cut

Comment: Ok, what's the trick? I'm not getting my new keyboard shortcuts to cause that command to kick off.

I've tried assigning it to a global F3 (because I don't ever use it, even though I know what it is for) after I removed that from Find Again and I know there's nothing else associated to it. It's still not executing. ~ Thoughts ideas?

Comment: @drachenstern you say that you're able to view, edit, create sprocs, etc. are you actually able to execute? I mean in some way other than a keyboard shortcut? MSDN has this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yea4bc1b(vs.80).aspx

Comment: Yes I can run the scripts if I click the button on the toolbar. I can also run the scripts by going to the Data menu and clicking Transact-Sql Editor, then Execute SQL. I just want to assign it to a keystroke. Something tells me I'm missing something really obvious.